# Pass Cell-Array as function argument from Python to Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, cell-array

I want to call a Matlab function from Python that takes a cell array as argument.

```
    eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
    eng.myfunct(cell)
```

An example 3x1 cell might be as follows:

```
    cell = [  [ [1,1],[2,2],[3,3] ],  [ [4,4],[5,5] ], [ [6,6],[7,7] ]  ]
```

So, first position in the cell would be a 3x2 matrix, second position a 2x2 matrix, and third position a 2x2 matrix.

Which data structure should I use? I have tried different combinations of python lists and numpy arrays that do not work.

Comment: Maybe make your `myfunct` function take a simple type like a string and then encode your data structure into that string using something JSON. Then in your MATLAB function you just need to convert the string to a cell array and I imagine there is JSON to cell-array code out there. I'm also sure there is Python list or tuple to JSON code out there.

Comment: I will check using JSON, but there should be some "cleaner" way to convert a python list (or similar) to cell array.